# `decide equality` for Mutually Recursive Types in Coq?

Tags: functional-programming, coq, dependent-type, theorem-proving, coq-tactic

Is there any way to use the `decide equality` tactic with mutually recursive types in Coq?

For example, if I've got something like this:

```
Inductive LTree : Set :=
  | LNil
  | LNode (x: LTree) (y: RTree)
  with RTree : Set :=
    | RNil
    | RNode (x: Tree) (y: RTree).

Lemma eq_LTree : forall (x y : LTree), {x = y} + {x <> y}.
Proof.
    decide equality; auto.
```

This leaves me with the goal:

```
y0: RTree
y1: RTree
{y0 = y1} + {y0 <> y1}
```

But I can't solve that until I've derived equality for `RTree`, which will have the same problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `decide equality` in this case if you prove the two lemmas for `LTree`s and `RTree`s simultaneously:

```
Lemma eq_LTree : forall (x y : LTree), {x = y} + {x <> y}
with  eq_RTree : forall (x y : RTree), {x = y} + {x <> y}.
Proof.
  decide equality.
  decide equality.
Qed.
```

Comment: This is strange, `Guarded` complains after the first `decide equality`, but then `Qed` is not rejected.

Comment: Never mind, I found a [thread](https://sympa.inria.fr/sympa/arc/coq-club/2011-11/msg00297.html) on coq-club discussing this particular problem.